# Where in the target directory is the product built by Tycho?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I am trying to learn about building Eclipse applications with Maven/Tycho. I wrote a plugin, which was running separately from within Eclipse.

Now I want to distribute it.

I made three maven projects. Topmost "parent" project contains the global settings for the Tycho plugin. Its children are a "plugin" project, which contains my plugin I mentioned above, and a "product" project, which contains single product definition file. I have created it mostly by default.

When I run Maven's "clean install" within "product" project, it's "target" directory is filled with some files and Maven reported "success".

Unfortunetely, I see not any executable or jar file to run within "target" directory.

Content of target directory:

```
D:\...se-rcp-kepler\programwfork4\com.scisbo.programwfork4\product\target>dir
 Volume in drive D is DATA02
 Volume Serial Number is D886-B5CD

 Directory of D:\Users\Dims\Design\eclipse-rcp-kepler\programwfork4\com.scisbo.programwfork4\product\target

18.03.2014  14:43    <DIR>          .
18.03.2014  14:43    <DIR>          ..
18.03.2014  14:43    <DIR>          classes
18.03.2014  14:43           127 185 com.scisbo.eclipse.programw.product-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
18.03.2014  14:43    <DIR>          extraArtifacts
18.03.2014  14:43               401 local-artifacts.properties
18.03.2014  14:43    <DIR>          p2agent
18.03.2014  14:43               636 p2artifacts.xml
18.03.2014  14:43            31 197 p2content.xml
18.03.2014  14:43    <DIR>          products
18.03.2014  14:43    <DIR>          repository
18.03.2014  14:43    <DIR>          targetPlatformRepository
```

What is it in target directory and how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

The generated products are placed inside the products directory, as exploded directories as well as zip files.

Comment: In products directory I have `product` subdirectory and it has the only file inside -- my product file I created. No any EXEs or JARs.

Comment: Could you please add the your build log (at least for the product), your product file and product pom?

Comment: Also: what happens if your create the product from the eclipse?

Comment: I think this is impossible, since product project contains nothing but product file. Only Maven connects them.

Comment: Ah no, I was wrong. Eclipse export creates 2 subdirectories `eclipse` and `repository`, where `eclipse` contains `eclipse.exe` to run (actually it causes error if running)